# how to show currency symbol instead of 3-letter code in LWC datatable column?

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

I have a datatable with a currency column. My column definition is:

```
summaryDataColumns = [
    {
      type: "text",
      label: "Summary",
      fieldName: "sumName"
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      label: "Taxes",
      fieldName: "taxName",
      hideDefaultActions: true
    },
    {
      type: "currency",
      label: "",
      fieldName: "subtotal",
      hideDefaultActions: true,
      typeAttributes: {
        currencyCode: "USD"
      }
    }
  ];
```

the currency column shows something like `USD 300.00`. I need to show the currency symbol instead of the currency code. Something like `$ 300.00` is what I need. How do you do it?

update Oct 20: my updated columns definition is:

```
  summaryDataColumns = [
    {
      type: "text",
      label: "Summary",
      fieldName: "sumName"
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      label: "Taxes",
      fieldName: "taxName",
      hideDefaultActions: true
    },
    {
      type: "currency",
      label: "",
      fieldName: "subtotal",
      hideDefaultActions: true,
      typeAttributes: {
        currencyCode: "USD",
        currencyDisplayAs: "symbol"
      }
    }
  ];
```

however, it does not seem to make any difference in the lwc datatable. 3 letter code still showing up:
[image]

Comment: Does it allow you to change the currency code line to a $? I.e. changing currencyCode: "USD" to currencyCode: "$"?

Comment: @Instread no, it does not accept $. It throws an error

Answer (score 1):

To display the value as *$ num* instead of *USD num*, include `currencyDisplayAs: "symbol"` in the `typeAttributes`.

For more details on data table type attributes, refer to ***Formatting with Data Types*** section [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation).

---

*Ref screenshot for USD formatted display:*

[image]

Comment: It is still showing the 3-letter code...

Comment: Did you mean it is showing _US$_ or _USD_? Could you post the updated code (and provide screenshot)?

Comment: I need to show "$ 000" instead of "USD 000". I am not sure it this has to do with multi currency being disabled

Comment: Multi-currency settings could be a factor, although I have not verified that at my end. But, after including the `currencyDisplayAs` type attribute, it should definitely not show up as `USD` (and I have verified this in my dev org). I'm assuming that you have refreshed the page (with clearing cache) or tried it in a different browser.

Comment: Yes, I have cleared cache and reloaded 3 times the page. The changes in the code are there, but table still shows 3-letter currency code. I wonder, does your dev org have multi currency enabled?

Comment: I've tried in orgs with multi-currency enabled as well as disabled and can conclude that this setting has nothing to do with data displayed in lightning data table. I'm able to see this change in a different browser and also, toggling the type attribute changes the currency display. I've pasted a ref screenshot in my answer.

Comment: @oabarca - did you ever resolve this? I am experiencing the exact same issue.

Comment: @oabarca - did you ever resolve this? I am experiencing the exact same issue